# Serialize Scala spark model with MLEAP and serve in Python environment

Tags: python, apache-spark, mleap

Is it possible to train a model in scala environment, serialize it with mleap and then serve on a different python server? I've read the docs, but it still isn't clear to me how compatible those things are

Comment: Usually, you do it the other way around. mleap helps you with serving models on non-python servers. can you please elaborate on your case?

Comment: Our case is that nobody really knows scala enough to write model's backend in it.

Comment: @orlevii why do you want to serve model in non python environment tho?

Comment: Can I ask why is your model written in scala? Is it for using spark MLlib?

Comment: I think it's much easier to use the same language for training and serving ML models, things are much more compatible this way.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that mleap is not language-dependent. Isn't it?

Comment: It isn't language-dependent, mlleap allows you to serialize models trained with sklean/spark/tensorflow and load them with their SDK. Usually, data scientists go-to language is python, where their full stack of pandas, numpy and other utilities are available. But here you are trying to do the other way around, so I'm a little confused